# Ruby on rails is not working on Windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to set up Ruby development environment . I have a new Lenevo Idea pad laptop . I need help on the below error.

Could not find gem 'turbolinks (~> 5) x86-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems .

Comment: Welcome to sstackoverflow, did you follow the getting started guide https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html, it will help with windows but I highly recommend you setup a linux virtual machine or dual boot and develop in that

Comment: did you try to run `bundle install` ?  But also for serious Rails work you might consider using Linux subsystem. See (this tutorial)[https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10].  I prefer RVM over RBENV but either should work.

Comment: @lacostenycoder You switched your [] and your ().